# ImageView not fading in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to get a fading effect on the ImageView when collapsing the AppbarLayout but the image still remains. I have read other solutions but its not working for me. I cant seem to find what is wrong with the code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutProfile"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.bolt.citywatch.ui.fragment.ProfileFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Hi! did you find out what was the problem? Thanks!

Comment: try adding attribute app:contentScrim="@color/fadecolor" in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Is your RecyclerView big enough to cause the scroll?

Comment: Its fade to app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"

Answer (score 10):

If everything is working fine for you but you just need the image to fade as the `AppBarLayout` collapses, you can set up an `addOnOffsetChangedListener` that will detect how much the app bar has closed. So, when the app bar is 100% open, the alpha value of the image will be set to 255 (opaque) assuming that we are using `setImageAlpha()` of `ImageView` and transparent (zero) when the app bar is completely closed. (See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha(int))).

Here is the code snippet to make this happen. I place it in `onCreate()` of the activity:

```
final ImageView profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
final AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBar);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        float range = (float) -appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        profileImage.setImageAlpha((int) (255 * (1.0f - (float) verticalOffset / range)));
    }
});
```

Here is an example of the results:

[image]

If this is not exactly what you are looking for, you can also consider `contentScrim`, `scrimAnimationDuration` and `scrimVisibleHeightTrigger` of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: Awarding bounty here as it answers both the `scrim` issue (which will fade out the content of the bar upon locking) and the gradual fade (which requires custom code as described)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling upon this as I did and isn't satisfied with the accepted answer, as the image is supposed to fade out on its own without tinkering the code, make sure your `Toolbar` is the last child of your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, and not your `ImageView`... found the answer on [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/). Fixed it for me.

Comment: The link results in a 404

Answer (score 2):

ImageView (or whatever content) will only fade if you have give a `contentScrim` property like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/toolbarColor"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Whatever you want to fade content goes here. -->

        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title="Your investments" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Note that `app:contentScrim="@color/toolbarColor"` is important.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your problem exactly. But here is my working code.

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivParallax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```